# display none on hover don't work properly css

Tags: html, css, hover, block

i have a div(1) on top of another div(2) and i want that div(2) hide on hover. i do that with display: block and on hover display: none. 
This won't work properly it flickers if you hover it. one sec it hides and than it pops up again.
my code is:

HTML

```
<hgroup>
    <article>
        <div class="filter" >

        </div>
    </article>
<hgroup>
```

CSS;

```
hgroup {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: scroll;}

article {   
      background-image:url('../ad-travelfoto.png');
      width: 1000px;
      height: 578px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      margin-top: 100px;
      box-shadow: 1px 0px 7px black;
      background-size: cover;}

article:last-child{
      margin-bottom: 100px;}

.filter {
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
     height: 578px;
     width: 1000px;}

.filter:hover {
     display: none;}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That's happening because once it displays to none, you're not technically hovered on that element anymore.

Try using `opacity: 0;` instead

Comment: thank you very much! this was driving me crazy for so long! it's working now!

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion when you set `opacity:0` then it's still there, so you cannot click anything under a div that is invisible. If you need it this .filter to be really gone, in your case, I suggest you to use:

```
.filter:hover {
 display: none;
}
article:hover .filter {
 display:none
}
```