# How to make text appear on hover within a div?

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to make text appear (with some styling) upon hover. I tried to use display:none; and then with hover display:block; but this hasnt worked.

```
<div class="container-fluid sub-head">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md left">
          <div class="title">Title</div>
          <div class="overlay">
            <div class="overlay-content">
              <p>
                some text
              </p>
              <p>more text.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md right">
          <div class="title">other title</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col-md {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  height: 100px;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  display:none;
}

.overlay:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

fiddle is here;
http://jsfiddle.net/2dyvLf5o/14/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see content of p element (more text), you should define a class name for this element and set hover style to it`s parent div, I also put title inside overlay div

```html
enter code here
```

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col-md {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
}
.overlay{
   height:150px
}

.hidden-content {
  display: none;
}

.overlay:hover .hidden-content{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid sub-head">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md left">
      <div class="overlay">
        <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
        <div class="overlay-content">
          <p>
            some text
          </p>
          <p class="hidden-content">more text.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md right">
      <h1 class="title">other title</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `:hover` on a parent element, like this:

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col-md {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  height: 100px;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.row:hover .overlay {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid sub-head">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md left">
      <div class="title">Title</div>
      <div class="overlay">
        <div class="overlay-content">
          <p>
            some text
          </p>
          <p>more text.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md right">
      <div class="title">Other title</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18219732/display-none-on-hover-dont-work-properly-css
You cannot hover an element that is not displayed.

Comment: You might want to use `opacity` to hide your text: http://jsfiddle.net/4m09b1s8/